# How to write combinations recursively in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a program for finding `combination(n Choose r = nCr)` using for loop/iterations, wanted to know how to do the same using recursion.
Code is as follows:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 int n,r;
 float num = 1,denum = 1,comb = 1;
 cout<<"Enter the values of n and r in nCr \n";
 cin>>n>>r;

 for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)
 {
    num *= (n-r+i);
 }
 for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)
 {
    denum *= (i);
 }
 comb = num/denum;
 cout<<"The number of combinations is "<<comb<<"\n";    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code that I've written helps in finding nCr through recursion:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

float comb(int n,int r){ 
    if(r!=0)
    {
        return (n-r+1)*comb(n,r-1)/r;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }      
}

int main(){
    int n,r;
    float com;
    cout<<"Enter the values of n and r in nCr \n";
    cin>>n>>r;
    if(n-r>=r)
    {
        com = comb(n,r);
    }
    else
    {
        com = comb(n,n-r);
    }

    cout<<"The number of combinations is "<<com<<"\n";    
}
```

Had done this program recently, upon calling the com function in main(), the function is calling itself(i.e recurses) until r value becomes 0 after which it goes to the base statement i.e return 1 if r equals 0

Comment: Is this the kind of recursion you want or do you want to do it using factorials

Answer (score 0):

**If you just need a code, here it is**

```
int findNumerator(int num, int i, int r) {
    return num * (i != r ? findNumerator(num, i+1, r) : 1);
}

int findDenominator(int denum, int i, int r) {
    return denum * (i != r ? findDenominator(denum, i+1, r) : 1);
}

int main(){
    int n,r;
    float num = 1,denum = 1,comb = 1;
    cout<<"Enter the values of n and r in nCr \n";
    cin>>n>>r;
    comb = findNumerator(num, 1, r) / findDenominator(denum, 1, r);

    cout<<"The number of combinations is "<<comb<<"\n";
}
```